# IdenityServer3 with ASP.NET WEB API 2 is giving authorization denied message

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver4, identityserver3

As part of API validation, we created an identity server using the **IdenityServer4** NuGet package and net core. Our existing API's are running in **ASP.NET WEB API 2**. Since the IdenityServer4 NuGet package is not compactable with WEB API 2, we used the **IdenityServer3** NuGet package to validate the token. We were able to get token from Idenityserver, but when we pass this token to the API(in the header), it says - **"Authorization has been denied for this request."**. What am I doing wrong here?

Startup class(In WEB API)

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebApplication2.Startup))]
namespace WebApplication2
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = "https://localhost:44385/",
                RequiredScopes = new[] { "offline_access openid api/Default" }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The URL - https://localhost:44385/ is where my IdenityServer is running.

and my Controller class is something as shown below

```
[Authorize]
public class DefaultController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

My Postman request screenshots on how I'm calling my API

[image]

Comment: It's a guess, so sorry if I'm wrong. But I see similarities. Can you verify the token header type (you can use jwt.io to decode the access token)? If this is "at+jwt" then that's the problem.

Comment: Yes. The token type is  - "typ": "at+jwt" when I decode it @RuardvanElburg

Comment: Then that's most likely the problem. Also take a look at the issue [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/3705).

Comment: Thanks @RuardvanElburg. I changed Idenityserver to return JWT, but still, I get the same authorization denied message.

Comment: Check the audience as well, as mentioned in the issue I've linked in my earlier comment.